# IIS6 all websites displays another site when using https

Tags: iis-6, http, https

I have the following websites set up in iis 6.

site1.com
site2.com
site3.com

Accessing site1 is via the address https://site1.com. Accessing site2 and site three should be through http.

When I try to access https://site2.com it displays the website of https://site1.com. How can I stop this. I either want an error or rediericting to the http site.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of way to do this Lisa , Yo can change your SSL port from 443 to 444 but from nowon you have to try https://site2.com:444 , or you can change Ip address form all unassigned to a new one ( properties of site2 --> web site tab ) .